# Unable to read libra excel file using Spreadsheet::XLSX module in Perl

Tags: perl, cpan

I am using `Spreadsheet::XLSX` to read excel file which has been created on Linux machine. But at the time of creating object using `Spreadsheet::XLSX->new("abc.xlsx");` I am getting following warning messages:

`Use of uninitialized value within @styles in hash element at
/usr/share/perl5/Spreadsheet/XLSX.pm line 189.
Use of uninitialized value $thisstyle in pattern match (.m//) at
/usr/share/perl5/Spreadsheet/XLSX.pm line 190.`

After this while reading the content of the excel file using the created object I am unable to read the content correctly

Can someone please help me with the following?

Comment: Can you give a link to a sample spreadsheet? Then others can at verify if the problem is related to a given platform..

Answer (score 0):

The warning you are seeing seems to be somewhat common:
https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=67755

I don't know if your having an issue with the document and can't tell however, you can silence the warnings via

```
$SIG{'__WARN__'} = sub { warn $_[0] unless (caller eq "Spreadsheet::XLSX"); }
```